# Converting Parquet to csv and vice versa without schema issues by using Pyspark dataframe

Tags: csv, schema, parquet, pyspark

Converting Parquet to csv and vice versa without schema issues by using Pyspark dataframe.

I did the following:

```
df=spark.read.parquet("part-00000-caae021e-9d02-46e8-a38d-5eaee04f1a03-c000.snappy.parquet")
df.printSchema()
df1=df.write.csv("test.csv", header=True)
```

Now I have updated the some values of specific fields in csv and then converted back csv to parquet as below

```
sample = spark.read.csv("test.csv", header=True)
sample.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("test.snappy.parquet")
```

But I'm facing data incompatibility errors, it's might be schema changed while modifying the values in csv. Am I missed anything here

Comment: do you have complex types in your dataframe? if yes they are not supported in csv format. Use json or parquet

Comment: what did you change, did your modification incur any datatype change of a column/field?